# How to match a model 'A' with an attribute of a model 'B'?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm a French student and I'm learning some Django. My project is to create a web site that allows you to manage a sport tournament. 
Here is my class diagram :

http://prntscr.com/nc39r8

I have an attribute "nbMaxTeam" in Tournament table, if this attribute is equal to 4 for example, I want that when I create a 5th team related to a tournament it tells me that is impossible. How do I do that with my models ?

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    nbplayers   = models.IntegerField()
    totalpoints = models.IntegerField()
    position    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pool        = models.ForeignKey(Pool, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tournament  = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    dateStart   = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    dateEnd     = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    nbMaxTeam   = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the number of teams that already belongs to your tournament in your views.py.

For example, when adding a team to your first tournament:

```
def create_team(request):
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id=1)
    if tournament.nbMaxTeam < 4:
        team = Team.objects.create(tournament=tournament)
    else:
        # Do something else...
```

Comment: I wanted to do that directly in the model but in the view it will work good too !

Comment: You can do this in multiple ways: in your model, you can override the save() method in order to implement this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to look at the docs, specifically model validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#id1